# Show there is no UMP test for $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Here's a testing problem.

> $X_1, \cdots, X_n, indep,   \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where $\mu, \sigma^2$ are unknown.
>
> $H_0: \mu \le \mu_0$ vs $H_1: \mu > \mu_0$ where $\mu_0$ is specified.

I need to prove that there's no UMP level $\alpha \in (0, 1/2)$ test.

Any hints or comments you can give me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you know that there is a stats site in the SE network?

Comment: No. I tried to find it but I couldn't. Could you let me know?

Comment: At the bottom of this page I see a list of SE sites. In the column headed "Science", I see one with the word "stats" in it.

Comment: Oh, Crossvalidated. I overlooked that, thx.